# Linear transformation of random vector has bounded moments?

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-problem, multivariate-statistical-analysis

Suppose that the random $p$-vector $\mathbf{y}=(Y_1, Y_2,\ldots, Y_p)'$
with $p\to\infty$ satisfies:

- $\mathrm{E}Y_i = 0$, $\mathrm{E}Y_i^2=1$ for any $1\leqslant i \leqslant p$;
- $\mathrm{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$
- for any $m\geqslant 1$ and $1\leqslant i \leqslant p$, $\sup\limits_{p\geqslant 1}\mathrm{E}Y_{i}^m < \infty$.

The $p\times p$ matrix $\mathbf{A}_p$ has bounded spectral norm, that is, $\sup\limits_{p\geqslant 1}\|\mathbf{A}_p\|_2 = \sup\limits_{p\geqslant 1}\left(\max\limits_{|\mathbf{x}|_2\neq 0}\frac{|\mathbf{A}_p\mathbf{x}|_2}{|\mathbf{x}|_2}\right)<\infty$.
Denote $\widetilde{\mathbf{y}}=\mathbf{A}_p\mathbf{y}=(\widetilde{Y}_1, \widetilde{Y}_2, \dots, \widetilde{Y}_p)$.

**Question**: Does $\sup\limits_{p\geqslant 1}\mathrm{E}\widetilde{Y}_i^m<\infty$ for any $m\geqslant 1$ and any $1\leqslant i \leqslant p$?

It is obvious that the expectation $\mathrm{E}(\widetilde{\mathbf{y}})=\boldsymbol{0}$, but I do not know how to deal with higher-order moments.

Answer (score 1):

$\tilde{Y}_1 = \sum_{i=1}^p c_i Y_i$. As $Y_i \in L_m$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) we have $\sum_{i=1}^p c_i Y_i \in L_m$ because $L_m$ is a linear space (it follows from Minkowski inequality, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: Hi Botnakov. Thank you for your answer. I think your answer is correct when $p$ is finite. I want to know whether $\mathrm{E}Y_i^m<\infty$ with $p\to \infty$ (forgot to mention this in the original version of this question) and I have edited the question. Thanks again!

Comment: @MHMH  What do you mean by $EY_i^m < \infty$, $p \to \infty$? For $p=1$ we proved that $EY_i^m < \infty$.  For $p=2$ we proved that $EY_i^m < \infty$. And so on. Maybe you want smth.like $\sup_{p \ge 1} EY_i^m < \infty$?

Comment: Yes, I want to show that $\sup_{p\geqslant 1} \mathrm{E}\widetilde{Y}_i^m<\infty$.

Comment: @MHMH Do you suppose that $\sup_{p \ge 1} ||A|| < \infty?$ Or smth.like $\sup_p EY_i^m < \infty$ for all $m$?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that $\sup\limits_{p\geqslant 1} \|\mathbf{A}_p\|_2 < \infty$ and $\sup\limits_{p\geqslant 1}\mathbb{E}Y_i^m<\infty$. I edit my question again, sorry for my imprecise statement:(

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Consider $(Y_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ i.i.d. $N(0,1)$-distributed. Define the matrices $$A_p=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots &\dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2  &0& \dots &0&0 \\
\dots  \\ 0 & 0 &\dots &\dots &0 & p
\end{pmatrix}$$ Then clearly $\mathbb E |\widetilde Y_p|^m \to \infty$ for $m>1$.

If we furthermore assume $\sup_{p\geq 1}\Vert A_p\Vert_2=\Lambda<\infty$, then we have $$\mathbb E|\widetilde Y_i|^m = \mathbb E| (A_pY)_i|^m\leq \Lambda^m \mathbb E|Y_i|^m\leq \Lambda ^m \sup_{j\geq 1}\mathbb E|Y_j|^m<\infty$$

Comment: Hi @Small Deviation. Thanks for your answer. I make some vague claims in the original question. Actually, I suppose that $\sup\limits_{p} \|\mathbf{A}\|<\infty$. Your $\mathbf{A}_p$ fails to support this assumption, since $\sup\limits_{p}\|\mathbf{A}_p\|=p\to\infty$.

Comment: @MHMH I have changed my answer to include this assumption. But in the future, please try to avoid changing your question multiple times.

Comment: Could you explain why $\mathbb{E}|(\mathbf{A}_p Y)_i|^m \leqslant \Lambda^m \mathbb{E}|Y_i|^m$?